# Single CFIDE folder for multiple instance multiserver configuration in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, multiserver

Recently working with ColdFusion enterprise version multiserver installation.

I have created three instances 1. cfusion (default) 2. cfserver1 and 3. cfserver2. Basically I want to control one site on two different instances and load sharing between them. I created cluster and add both cfserver1 and cfserver2 instances into it and later configure website on IIS 7 and attach with cluster through "Web server configuration" tool. Everything is working fine but only issue was it wasn't stick with session as I forgot to enable "User J2ee session variables". Here is my issue... I need to open separate CFIDE for both instances and enable it separately. Also I need to create database source on both places.

Can we share CFIDE of one instance with another one?

**Update [7/4/2011]**

Well I am able to share CFIDE between two instances but still issue with duplicate setting. As most of setting reside under WEB-INF folders I have to create separate settings for each instance? 
Do anyone have idea about sharing WEB-INF or any how same settings (datasources and others) share by all instances?

To share CFIDE follow below steps...
Sharing CFIDE between two instance. 
1. Copy CFIDE folder to another place.
2. Create virtual path in jrun-web.xml file available under WEB-INF folder pointing to new physical location of CFIDE.
 
     /CFIDE/*
     C:/projects/CFIDE

Comment: Adding CFIDE as virtual directory in IIS doesn't work as both servers in cluster so new settings only apply for whichever server instance processing request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't manage the CF admin settings for multiple servers from the one console. The clustering only handles session management. 
As you've found out, you can use one copy of CFIDE to manage more than one CF server instance, but the changes only apply to the server handling your request. 
As of CF8, you can manage almost everything in the web administrator through the administrative API. If you need to make regular or scripted changes to datasources and the like, I'd use the API and some kind of script to invoke it on each server, or process the file on application start and set up the DSN and other settings.

Alternatively, just accept the need to update both instances, which is irritating, but may be an acceptable risk

Comment: Thanks barnyr, This is what I discover in last two days, noway to share WEB-INF...